# Procrun (prunsrv.exe) fails to find jvm.dll automatically with JDK 11

Tags: java, java-11, apache-commons-daemon, prunsrv

Using the latest Apache Commons Daemon 1.2.0 on a Windows machine with JDK 11, it fails to automatically find the jvm.dll file and throws the following error:

```
( javajni.c:227 ) [ 4588] Invalid RuntimeLib ''
```

I need to open the properties of the service and manually point it to the jvm.dll file in my JDK installation directory.

Is there a way I can set it to automatically find the file, when the service is installed? JDK 8 works like a charm.

Comment: *JDK 8 works like a charm*. I suspect that might be your answer.

Comment: According to the Apache documentation, when the JVM parameter is set to auto, prunsrv should attempt to find the jvm.dll on its own, but it fails to do so.

"Use either auto (i.e. find the JVM from the Windows registry) or specify the full path to the jvm.dll. You can use environment variable expansion here."

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html